# Firth's method for logistic regression - interpretation of R output

Tags: r, multinomial-logit, profile-likelihood

I have a multivariate, multinomial logistic regression model with exclusively continuous covariates. After some examination, I found that I had a problem of quasi-complete separation. The textbook Applied Regression Analysis (3rd Ed, Hosmer, Lemeshow, and Sturdivant) recommends trying Firth's method or perhaps a Bayesian method. I am starting with Firth's method. I have 16,000 observations (1000 per class for 16 classes), and no missing data. I have three covariates: `total_length`, `total_num_peak` and and `total_peak`. My response is called `class_var`.

After proceeding according to the textbook's recommended model fitting technique presented in Chapter 4, I found that I should retain all of these continuous variables. I then attempted to test the hypothesis of a linear relationship between each continuous variable and the polychotomous response using fractional polynomials, as they suggested.

```
require(mfp)

fp_trial1 <- mfp(class_val ~ fp(total_length_data) + fp(total_num_data) + fp(total_peak_data), data=datatouse, family=binomial, select=0.05, verbose=TRUE)
...
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> summary(fp_trial1)

Call:
glm(formula = class_val ~ I((total_length_data/10)^2) + I((total_length_data/10)^3) + 
    I((total_num_data/100)^-2) + I((total_num_data/100)^-2 * 
    log((total_num_data/100))) + I((total_peak_data/10)^1) + 
    I((total_peak_data/10)^2), family = binomial, data = datatouse)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-3.00748   0.00000   0.00000   0.00055   2.46316  

Coefficients:
                                                       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                                             100.924      5.207  19.381   <2e-16 ***
I((total_length_data/10)^2)                             -34.991      2.814 -12.433   <2e-16 ***
I((total_length_data/10)^3)                              18.664      1.529  12.210   <2e-16 ***
I((total_num_data/100)^-2)                              -35.320      3.009 -11.737   <2e-16 ***
I((total_num_data/100)^-2 * log((total_num_data/100)))  -66.504      5.476 -12.145   <2e-16 ***
I((total_peak_data/10)^1)                              -136.221     13.221 -10.303   <2e-16 ***
I((total_peak_data/10)^2)                                91.753     10.636   8.627   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 7481.3  on 15999  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1889.3  on 15993  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1903.3

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 20
```

The resulting model `fp_trial1` gives me warnings: `glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred` (of course, due to quasi-complete separation). This warning was not given in any of my earlier models without fractional polynomials.

I saved the transformed continuous variables:

```
trans_length_1 <- I((total_length_data/10)^2)
trans_length_2 <- I((total_length_data/10)^3)
trans_num_1 <- I((total_num_data/100)^-2)
trans_num_2 <- I((total_num_data/100)^-2*log((total_num_data/100)))
trans_peak_1 <- I((total_peak_data/10)^1)
trans_peak_2 <- I((total_peak_data/10)^2)
```

The textbook and several other sources recommend trying either Firth's method or Bayesian methods to correct the maximum likelihood estimates of the model coefficients.

I tried Firth's method twice.

First on the non-transformed, original continuous variables (no fractional polynomials):

```
firth_try1 <- logistf(class_val ~ ., data=datatouse)
summary(firth_try1)
 logistf(formula = class_val ~ ., data = datatouse)

 Model fitted by Penalized ML
 Confidence intervals and p-values by Profile Likelihood Profile Likelihood Profile Likelihood Profile Likelihood 

                          coef    se(coef)   lower 0.95 upper 0.95 Chisq p
 (Intercept)       -2.50000000 0.175378167 -10.39062500 2.26562500   Inf 0
 total_length_data  0.06628730 0.003100900   0.04584702 0.19903127   Inf 0
 total_num_data     0.06105918 0.002287816   0.02537920 0.18539528     0 1
 total_peak_data   -0.07018389 0.006479825  -0.29286360 0.09274219     0 1

 Likelihood ratio test=-21655.99 on 3 df, p=1, n=16000
 Wald test = 820.1223 on 3 df, p = 0

 Covariance-Matrix:
               [,1]          [,2]          [,3]          [,4]
 [1,]  3.075750e-02 -3.941999e-04 -3.772134e-04 -2.856177e-05
 [2,] -3.941999e-04  9.615581e-06  4.646448e-06 -1.184615e-05
 [3,] -3.772134e-04  4.646448e-06  5.234104e-06 -5.554578e-07
 [4,] -2.856177e-05 -1.184615e-05 -5.554578e-07  4.198813e-05
```

Then again on the variables given by fractional polynomials:

```
firth_try2 <- logistf(class_val ~ trans_length_1 + trans_length_2 + trans_num_1 + trans_num_2 + trans_peak_1 + trans_peak_2)
summary(firth_try2)

logistf(formula = class_val ~ trans_length_1 + trans_length_2 + 
    trans_num_1 + trans_num_2 + trans_peak_1 + trans_peak_2)

Model fitted by Penalized ML
Confidence intervals and p-values by Profile Likelihood Profile Likelihood Profile Likelihood Profile Likelihood Profile Likelihood Profile Likelihood Profile Likelihood 

                       coef     se(coef)   lower 0.95 upper 0.95 Chisq p
(Intercept)     3.676094920 0.0857621159   1.09207496 8.82242039     0 1
trans_length_1  0.051923748 0.0099138237  -0.36229140 1.55692375     0 1
trans_length_2 -0.003111276 0.0005995477  -0.09154265 0.03564788     0 1
trans_num_1     0.005308026 0.0245945989  -2.90622134 1.20618527   Inf 0
trans_num_2     0.004260134 0.0089617340  -1.06689900 0.43585198   Inf 0
trans_peak_1   -3.252855873 0.1775676130 -11.29973087 4.79401913   Inf 0
trans_peak_2    0.654467634 0.0469797867  -2.20852801 2.94285384   Inf 0

Likelihood ratio test=51782.11 on 6 df, p=0, n=16000
Wald test = 573.1425 on 6 df, p = 0

Covariance-Matrix:
              [,1]          [,2]          [,3]          [,4]          [,5]          [,6]          [,7]
[1,]  7.355141e-03  6.825870e-05 -4.644040e-06  3.629626e-04  1.414730e-04 -1.362181e-02  3.281189e-03
[2,]  6.825870e-05  9.828390e-05 -5.839621e-06 -1.961139e-04 -6.840045e-05  7.763108e-05 -4.100732e-05
[3,] -4.644040e-06 -5.839621e-06  3.594575e-07  1.136974e-05  4.020994e-06 -2.416920e-06  1.960277e-06
[4,]  3.629626e-04 -1.961139e-04  1.136974e-05  6.048943e-04  2.192665e-04 -1.846648e-03  3.596068e-04
[5,]  1.414730e-04 -6.840045e-05  4.020994e-06  2.192665e-04  8.031268e-05 -7.013629e-04  1.381739e-04
[6,] -1.362181e-02  7.763108e-05 -2.416920e-06 -1.846648e-03 -7.013629e-04  3.153026e-02 -7.559748e-03
[7,]  3.281189e-03 -4.100732e-05  1.960277e-06  3.596068e-04  1.381739e-04 -7.559748e-03  2.207100e-03
```

**Question**: How can I interpret the results of Firth's method?

**My guess**: In the fractional polynomial output for Firth's method, the Chi-squared test statistic gives `Inf` or `0`. In the case of `Inf`, that means the expected cell counts were 0. In the case of `0`, that means the expected cell counts matched the observed cell counts exactly. I think that means my quasi-complete separation is occurring due to `trans_length_1` and `trans_length_2`. Most of the confidence intervals contain 0, which to me means that most of my variables are not significant, but that doesn't make sense if there's quasi-complete separation (at least one variable must be significant, as it nearly perfectly predicts class identity).

Can anyone help fill in this analysis properly?